# Just common sense

Tags: wordplay

Below are nine ordered groups of words and phrases. Use common sense to solve the first eight. This should then tell you how to continue with the last group.

> - objective; break; happening at night; friend; dominant; not fake; stamp; beacon; complete
> - not before; personality; go in; trash; half of a half; enroll; male chicken; H2O
> - x or y, e.g.; set off; give away; dispose of; lucky; baby; finish
> - ammunition; cottage; fjord; brochure; lavatory; V in ROYGBIV
> - catastrophes; main office; Harry and Beatrix, e.g.; female siblings; authors
> - remote; concerning this; evidence; parody
> - something giving stability/balance; explosion; image-breaker
> - disappeared; 14 pounds
> - customs of a society

Good luck!

P.S.: A clue may be provided later, but not before you've found the solution.

Comment: Nice puzzle! I had fun trying this, especially as a few of us were racing ahead with our answers at the same time.

Comment: You guys were simply too fast for me. Chapeau!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The approach is:

> Find synonyms
>  Find the common last letters for each line
>  Together, they form a string

objective; break; happening at night; friend; dominant; not fake; stamp; beacon; complete

> **al**: goal, interval, nocturnal, pal, physical, original, seal, signal, total

not before; personality; go in; trash; half of a half; enroll; male chicken; H2O

> **ter**: after, character, enter, litter, quarter, enter, rooster, water

x or y, e.g.; set off; give away; dispose of; lucky; baby; finish

> **nate**: alternate, initiate, donate, terminate, fortunate, neonate, terminate

ammunition; cottage; fjord; brochure; lavatory; V in ROYGBIV

> **let**: bullet, chalet, inlet, pamphlet, toilet, violet

catastrophes; main office; Harry and Beatrix, e.g.; female siblings; authors

> **ters**: disasters, headquarters, potters, sisters, writers

remote; concerning this; evidence; parody

> **of**: aloof, of, proof, spoof

something giving stability/balance; explosion; image-breaker

> **last**: ballast, blast, iconoclast

disappeared; 14 pounds

> **one**: gone, stone

customs of a society

> **CULTURE**

String together the fragments to form:

> **Alternate letters of last one**

Which is:

> Alternate letters of CULTURE form CLUE

Which explains the statement "A clue may be provided later, but not before you've found the solution"

> Because the word clue is in the solution! :-)

Comment: Very good! You're the first to find the final one. I'm kicking myself for not having got it.

Comment: Thank you @JaapScherphuis . I spent a while picking the alternate letters of the answer to "disappeared / 14 pounds" and the phrase "customs of a society" before thinking "Why not get a single word for the last one", from which the 4 letter word popped out. Bit of luck, really.

Comment: well done, well guessed

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick - thank you. I thought I saw an answer from you also for this one?

Comment: @Phylyp. Yes, but when I posted it, two others already beat me to it. Since they were more complete than I had gotten so far, I just deleted mine.

Comment: "original"? "real" is a better synonym IMHO, and still fits the solution.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that for every group of words, there are synonyms which then end with the same syllable

For the group of 9

> objective -> goAL
>  stamp -> postAL
>  complete - toTAL

For the group of 8

> not before -> afTER
>  personality -> characTER
>  go in -> enTER

For the group of 7

> x or y -> coordiNATE

For the group of 6

> ammunition -> bulLET ; cottage -> hamLET ; brochure -> bookLET ; lavatory -> toiLET ; V in ROYGBIV -> vioLET (thanks to Kilhaul)

For the group of 5

> catastrophes -> twisTERS
>  Harry and Beatrix -> potTERS
>  female siblings -> sisTERS
>  authors -> wriTERS

For the group of 4

> evidence -> proOF
>  parody -> spoOF
>  remote -> far OFF
>  concerning this -> speaking OF

For the group of 3

> explosion -> bLAST

For the group of 2

> disappeared -> gONE
>  14 pounds -> stONE

Then it forms a sentence which reads

> AL-TER-NATE LET-TERS OF LAST ONE
>  Alternate letters of last one

*to be continued*

Comment: Well done, for the group of 6 I'd say : ammunition -> pelLET ; cottage -> hamLET ; brochure -> bookLET ; lavatory -> toiLET ; V in ROYGBIV -> vioLET

Answer (score 6):

Here's my partial answer:

objective; break; happening at night; friend; dominant; not fake; stamp; beacon; complete

> goal, interval, nocturnal, pal, influential, real, seal, signal, total

not before; personality; go in; trash; half of a half; enroll; male chicken; H2O

> after, character, enter, litter, quarter, register, rooster, water

x or y, e.g.; set off; give away; dispose of; lucky; baby; finish

> indeterminate, detonate, donate, eliminate, fortunate, neonate, terminate

ammunition; cottage; fjord; brochure; lavatory; V in ROYGBIV

> bullet, chalet, inlet, leaflet, toilet, violet

catastrophes; main office; Harry and Beatrix, e.g.; female siblings; authors

> disasters, headquarters, Potters, sisters, writers

remote; concerning this; evidence; parody

> aloof, hereof, proof, spoof

something giving stability/balance; explosion; image-breaker

> ballast, blast, iconoclast

disappeared; 14 pounds

> gone, stone

customs of a society

> ?

So that gives:

> al-ter-nate let-ters of last one ?

Comment: How about cardinal for the missing one in line one?

Comment: @KarstenKöpnick For the word cardinal I would have expected a different clue. I've now gone for "influential" instead.